# Most Efficient Way to Create New Column in Pandas from Existing One Based on Condition

Tags: pandas, loops

How would I create a new column from an existing column based on condition? I know I can do it with a for loop, but it's very inefficient.

For example, let's say I have a column 'Customer_Left' with a binomial value of 0 or 1. I want to create a new column ('Value') that assigns a value of 100 to that customer.

My code was this:

```
value = 100

for i in range(len(df['Customer_Left')):
    if df['Customer_Left'][i] == 1:
        df['Value'] = value
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A more general answer if you want to set a value to a subset of rows is to use .loc with a condition, such as:

```
df.loc[df['Customer_Left'] == 1, 'Value'] = value
```

In your case, you could simply do:

```
df['Value'] = df['Customer_Left'] * 100
```

Comment: Thanks! I must tired, because I should've thought of the latter one. In any case, good to know the general principal for the first one.